# Wordpress WP_Query() Not working properly

Tags: php

I would like to know why we get an error when we implement this code in our `sidebar.php`:

```
$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach($categories as $category) 
{ 
  printf('<h2>%s</h2><ul>', $category->cat_name);
  $posts = new WP_Query('cat='.$category->cat_ID);
  while($posts->have_posts())
  {     
    $posts->the_post();
    echo '<li>', the_title(), '</li>'; 
  }   
  print '</ul>';  
}
```

The error we are getting is:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php on line 2374

Comment: Which line is 2374?  Is your code being used in the loop?

Comment: yes its working fine . but its not showing the Post data and giving the error mentioned above

Comment: Which line is 2374?

Comment: We Posted wp_reset_postdata(); at the end of the while loop, it the error changed to this one "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_reset_postdata()" .

Comment: on this function. "function next_post() {

$this->current_post++;

$this->post = $this->posts[$this->current_post]; "[comment] Line number 2374 here is the problem [/comment] "
return $this->post;
}"

Comment: Can you edit the code surrounding line 2374 into your question?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar error when using a WP_Query as given at
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42334/16898.

I replaced the variable name $posts with an arbitrary name $mposts and the error was gone.

Comment: that's right. this solved my similar problem where I was using `$pages` as my variable. Some names might be reserved for wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes, probably if you have two queries in one page, you need to reset the query data, try to insert the code below after while loop:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Giving error when we placed it at the end. "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_reset_postdata()"